# Accessing Oracle NoSQL from Hive

Tags: oracle, hadoop, hive, hiveql, oracle-nosql

I'm following [this (pretty old) tutorial](https://blogs.oracle.com/NoSQL/entry/bigdata_sql_with_oracle_nosql) for accessing a local Oracle NoSQL DB from Hive using a StorageHandler.

I've successfully:

- Extracted Hadoop 2.7.2 under `/home/hadoop/hadoop`
- Extracted Hive 1.2.1 under `/home/hadoop/hive`
- Set the following environment variables:

  ```
  export HADOOP_HOME=/home/hadoop/hadoop
  export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
  export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
  export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
  export HADOOP_YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
  export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native"
  export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
  export KVHOME=/home/hadoop/kv
  export KVROOT=/tmp/kv-metadata
  export HIVE_HOME=/home/hadoop/hive/
  export HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH=$KVHOME/lib/kvclient.jar
  export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin:$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$HIVE_HOME/bin
  ```
- Run the Oracle NoSQL DB:

  ```
  java -jar $KVHOME/lib/kvstore.jar kvlite -root $KVROOT -host localhost &
  ```
- Created the `MOVIE` table in the Oracle DB

However, when I run `hive` and type

```
hive> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MOVIE( id INT, original_title 
STRING,    overview STRING, poster_path STRING, release_date STRING, 
vote_count INT,       runtime INT, popularity DOUBLE, genres STRING) 
STORED BY 'oracle.kv.hadoop.hive.table.TableStorageHandler' 
TBLPROPERTIES  ( "oracle.kv.kvstore"="kvstore",      
"oracle.kv.hosts"="localhost:5000", 
"oracle.kv.hadoop.hosts"="localhost",        
"oracle.kv.tableName"="MOVIE");
```

I get the following error:

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from 
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.
org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe.initSerdeParams
(Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;Ljava/util/Properties;Ljava    
/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/hive/serde2    
/lazy/LazySimpleSerDe$SerDeParameters;
```

Apparently, it seems a error related to the SerDe component.

I've tried also with Hive 2.0, but it doesn't work either.

Any clue of what is happening ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known problem, related to [HIVE-9500 introducing an incompatible change to LazySimpleSerDe public interface](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-12406">HIVE-12406<). **Switching to Hive 1.0.1** has solved the problem.